# application icon change its background color at iphone device

Tags: iphone

I have an icon.png which has white background with a blue faced cartoon. 
Something like the face of **[this](http://video.dancecompgenie.com/dancevideo/images/phone.png)** image.

But, when i see it in simulator/device than its background color change from white to black with blue face at always.

Does iphone change it to provide the aero effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ehm no, it doesn't... Are you sure the icon.png has a **white** background and is not **transparent**? And what are you using this for? Is the icon.png being used in your app itself, or is it the icon of your application?

If the icon.png is **transparent**, it might be caused by the background color of the UIView you are using it in. I suggest changing the icon.png or changing the background color of the view.

Comment: I am using icon.png as the icon of my app and not inside my app anywhere. I shall ask my designer to check if its transparent and comment again in 1 hour. Thanks. I think this transparent thing might be my issue.

Comment: that doesn't mean the icon doesn't have a transparent background. if you select it in xcode, is the background gray?

Comment: @Grady Player : Yea, its gray. It is same as the xcode background color when i see it in xcode. So, is it transparent?

Comment: @iMatoria yeah that means its transparent -- your problem

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Anstwan van Houdt. After your reply, i search iphone app icon against transparency and found below [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) link. It states that if we make a icon transparent that it would give black background color by default.

So, better we give it.